# Javascript Function test each array and return all in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

Hi everybody and thanks for your helps.

hi have a context here in a game engine, i would like know if existe a easy way to return each array ? Ex: [true,true,false,false]
here the snippet i make it more simple and clean to read , but is very similar to what i need to do.

```js
 Gate1 = [];
Gate1 = [[3,4],[4,6]]; // [[ItemID,NbItem],[ItemID,NbItem]]

function check(ID, NEED, GVariable) {
for (var F=0; F<ID.length; F++) {
var Founds = [ID[F],NEED[F]];
if (Founds === GVariable[F]){
//return stop the loop, but i need to test all ID.length and return true or false in array it in array
  return true;
  }
  else {return false;}
 }
}
var Get = check([3,4,10,11],[4,6,8,7],Gate1);
console.log(Get); //need to be ===  Get[[true,true,false,false]] 
alert("Gets= "+Get+'\n'+'But i want = [true,true,false,false]');
```

Comment: and what exactly is the logic, to decide whether it is true value of false in array?

Comment: example for test if the array GateX have all item recipe to build ex: the gate. If one false, cant not build, and is need to show why and where in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table and check against the value you need. Then return with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) an array with the result.

I strongly recommend to rename the variables to a more common style with small letters.

```js
function check(ID, NEED, GVariable) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);

    GVariable.forEach(function (a) {
        hash[a.join('|')] = true;
    });
    return ID.map(function (id, i) {
        return hash[[id, NEED[i]].join('|')] || false;
    });
}

var Gate1 = [[3, 4], [4, 6]], // [[ItemID,NbItem],[ItemID,NbItem]],
    Get = check([3, 4, 10, 11], [4, 6, 8, 7], Gate1);

console.log(Get); // [true, true, false, false]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: OMG NICE NICE , 
I am at the beginning, I do not know all the JavaScript trick.
Your code are very clean.
I will study more the map function.
Thank you so much friend.
For my variable names, I usually write in lowercase or uppercase according to their importance and their SCOPE.
Because some var are for a for a specific .js file, ans other need to use for all .js files.
I indeed exaggerate for this example.
Thank you so much for your help, you are great.

Comment: These possible to make this function functional, but with arrays in dynamic position.
`var Gate1 = [[4, 6],[3, 4]]` // Also Give [true, true, false, false]

Comment: the order does not matter. do you need the same order?

Comment: Sorry Yes, I had to make a bad entry.
Is true, the order does not matter.

**Yes for a version with the mandatory order.**
I will be curious to study the difference between the 2 codes.
This will be nice to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also zip your `ID` and `NEED` arrays and use the `every` function to compare zipped and `GVariable` arrays:

```js
function checkit(ID, NEED, GVariable) {
  var result = [], arrays = [ID, NEED];
  zipped = arrays[0].map(function(_,i){ 
      return arrays.map(function(array){return array[i]})
  });
  zipped.forEach(function(arr, idx) { 
    result.push(arr.every(function(elt, i) {
      return (elt == GVariable[i][idx]);
    }))
  })
  return result;
}

var Gate1 = [[3,4],[4,6]]; 
var Get = checkit([3,4,10,11],[4,6,8,7],Gate1);
console.log(Get);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this friend.
It's a very interesting way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...Use JSON.stringify()

```
Gate1 = [];
Gate1 = [[3,4],[4,6]]; // [[ItemID,NbItem],[ItemID,NbItem]]

function check(ID, NEED, GVariable) {
for (var F=0; F<ID.length; F++) {
var Founds = [ID[F],NEED[F]];
if (JSON.stringify(Founds) == JSON.stringify(GVariable[F])){
//return stop the loop, but i need to test all ID.length and return true or false in array it in array
        return true;
        }
        else {return false;}
    }
}
var Get = check([3,4,10,11],[4,6,8,7],Gate1);
console.log(Get); //need to be ===  Get[[true,true,false,false]] 
alert("Gets= "+Get+'\n'+'But i want = [true,true,false,false]');
```

Comment: JSON.stringify, nice found i will study this , is exact what i need.